# Saving theano/lasagne output parameters for future classification

Tags: python, numpy, theano, lasagne

I am trying to save my output parameters so I can continue training/ classifying at a later date.

I am currently using:

```
np.savez('model.npz', *lasagne.layers.get_all_param_values(network))

with np.load('model.npz') as f:
    param_values = [f['arr_%d' % i] for i in range(len(f.files))]
lasagne.layers.set_all_param_values(network, param_values)
```

as suggested [here](https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/blob/master/examples/mnist.py). But despite importing  get_all_param_values from lasagne, I keep getting the error:

> AttributeError: 'TensorVariable' object has no attribute 'get_params'

The layer I'm trying to save is:

```
    train_out = lasagne.layers.get_output(output, {input_var:x1, input2_var:x2, 
input3_var:x3}, deterministic=False)
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that

```
output
```

in your above code is your actual output layer, you should pass this layer to

```
get_all_params(...)
```

Passing

```
train_out
```

to it won't work, since the result of

```
get_params(...)
```

is a theano TensorVariable (as stated in the error message), not a lasagne.Layer object.

Comment: it was a silly coding error, as you said output was my output not train out, all fixed, thanks! PS. should I remove the questions if i figure out the problem myself?

Comment: I'm not sure. If you figured it out yourself, maybe post the solution just in case someone else runs into the same problem?